# With natbib citation package, how to make THREE authors appear on the citation in rmarkdown latex document

Tags: latex, r-markdown

Instead of *`Jones et al.`*, I want to make each author's name show up in my text citation until **three** with citation package natbib(from 4 authors it should be *Jones et al.*).
I tried `citet*{}` and `citet{}`, but they didn't work.
My `rmarkdown` code and `.bib` file are given as follows:

```
---
title: "Paper"   
thanks: 
author: |
  | \normalfont Joe
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
    citation_package: natbib
    fig_caption: true
    fig_height: 4.5
    fig_width: 8
link-citations: yes
toc: false
bibliography: /Users/references02.bib
biblio-style: apalike    
in_header: preamble.tex
keep_tex: yes
fontsize: 11pt
linestretch: 1.3
subparagraph: true
number_sections: true
geometry: margin=1in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{amsthm}
- \numberwithin{equation}{section}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{geometry}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \usepackage{verbatim}
- \usepackage{chronosys}
- \usepackage{stackengine}
- \usepackage{booktabs, colortbl, xcolor}
- \usepackage{babel}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
- \usepackage[font=small]{caption}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage{tabularx}
- \usepackage{pgfplots}
- \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
- \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
- \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
- \usepackage{filecontents}
- \newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
- \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
- \newtheorem{algorithem}{Algorithm}
- \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
- \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
- \usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
- \newenvironment{rcases}
  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}
- \renewcommand{\refname}{References}
- \UseRawInputEncoding
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \hypersetup{
     colorlinks=true,
     linkcolor=black,
     filecolor=blue,
     citecolor = blue,      
     urlcolor=blue,
     }
- \usepackage{subcaption}
- \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{flafter}
- \floatstyle{plaintop}
- \restylefloat{table}
- \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
- \setlength{\parskip}{0em}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage[style=english]{csquotes} 
- \usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}
- \creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{(\textcolor{red}{#1})}#3}
- \creflabelformat{figure}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \creflabelformat{table}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \creflabelformat{section}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \usepackage{dcolumn}
- \usepackage{rotating}
- \usepackage{siunitx}
---


blah blah  \cite{ennis2019} \cite{worldbank2017}
```

```
@article{ennis2019,
    author = {Ennis, Sean F and Gonzaga, Pedro and Pike, Chris},
    title = "{Inequality: A hidden cost of market power}",
    journal = {Oxford Review of Economic Policy},
    volume = {35},
    number = {3},
    pages = {518-549},
    year = {2019},
    month = {07},
    abstract = "{This paper explores the impact of competition on inequality by developing a new model to illustrate how higher profits from market power, and associated higher prices, could influence the distribution of wealth and income. We analyse data from eight OECD countriesâCanada, France, Germany, Korea, Japan, Spain, the United Kingdom, and the United States. In an average country in the sample, market power increases the wealth of the richest 10 per cent by between 12 and 21 per cent for a range of reasonable assumptions about savings behaviour, while it reduces the income of the poorest 20 per cent by 11 per cent or more. The results contribute to the economic literature on the origins of inequality, suggesting that lack of competition may be one source of economic inequality.}",
    issn = {0266-903X},
    doi = {10.1093/oxrep/grz017},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1093/oxrep/grz017},
    eprint = {https://academic.oup.com/oxrep/article-pdf/35/3/518/28929084/grz017.pdf},
}

@book{worldbank2017,
   author = "World Bank",
   title = "A Step Ahead: Competition Policy for Shared Prosperity and Inclusive Growth",
   year = "2017",
   pages = 245,
   url = "https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/content/publication/978-1-4648-0945-3",
   doi = "https://doi.org/https://doi.org/10.1596/978-1-4648-0945-3" 
}
```

Comment: use biblatex instead -- if your bibtex style does not happen to exactly what you want, biblatex is much more flexible and easier to modify.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, is there any way to easily transfer to biblatex with my current yaml header and .bib file?  I once tried but gets really messy and somewhat complicated, so I just quitted. Anyway I will try again, thanks.

Comment: sure, I posted an example as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `biblatex`.

If your `bibtex` style does not happen to be exactly what you want, `biblatex` is much more flexible and easier to modify.

```
---
title: "Paper"   
thanks: 
author: |
  | \normalfont Joe
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: true
    fig_height: 4.5
    fig_width: 8
toc: false
in_header: preamble.tex
keep_tex: yes
fontsize: 11pt
linestretch: 1.3
subparagraph: true
number_sections: true
geometry: margin=1in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{amsthm}
- \numberwithin{equation}{section}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{geometry}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \usepackage{verbatim}
- \usepackage{chronosys}
- \usepackage{stackengine}
- \usepackage{booktabs, colortbl, xcolor}
- \usepackage[english]{babel}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
- \usepackage[font=small]{caption}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage{tabularx}
- \usepackage{pgfplots}
- \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
- \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
- \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
- \usepackage{filecontents}
- \newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
- \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
- \newtheorem{algorithem}{Algorithm}
- \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
- \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
- \usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
- \newenvironment{rcases}
  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}
- \renewcommand{\refname}{References}
- \UseRawInputEncoding
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \hypersetup{
     colorlinks=true,
     linkcolor=black,
     filecolor=blue,
     citecolor = blue,      
     urlcolor=blue,
     }
- \usepackage{subcaption}
- \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{flafter}
- \floatstyle{plaintop}
- \restylefloat{table}
- \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
- \setlength{\parskip}{0em}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage[style=english]{csquotes} 
- \usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}
- \creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{(\textcolor{red}{#1})}#3}
- \creflabelformat{figure}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \creflabelformat{table}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \creflabelformat{section}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \usepackage{dcolumn}
- \usepackage{rotating}
- \usepackage{siunitx}
- \usepackage[natbib, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
- \addbibresource{bib.bib}
---


blah blah  \cite{ennis2019} \cite{worldbank2017}

\printbibliography
```

---

And the bib file without illegal characters like `â` :

```
@article{ennis2019,
    author = {Ennis, Sean F and Gonzaga, Pedro and Pike, Chris},
    title = "{Inequality: A hidden cost of market power}",
    journal = {Oxford Review of Economic Policy},
    volume = {35},
    number = {3},
    pages = {518-549},
    year = {2019},
    month = {07},
    abstract = "{This paper explores the impact of competition on inequality by developing a new model to illustrate how higher profits from market power, and associated higher prices, could influence the distribution of wealth and income. We analyse data from eight OECD countries Canada, France, Germany, Korea, Japan, Spain, the United Kingdom, and the United States. In an average country in the sample, market power increases the wealth of the richest 10 per cent by between 12 and 21 per cent for a range of reasonable assumptions about savings behaviour, while it reduces the income of the poorest 20 per cent by 11 per cent or more. The results contribute to the economic literature on the origins of inequality, suggesting that lack of competition may be one source of economic inequality.}",
    issn = {0266-903X},
    doi = {10.1093/oxrep/grz017},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1093/oxrep/grz017},
    eprint = {https://academic.oup.com/oxrep/article-pdf/35/3/518/28929084/grz017.pdf},
}

@book{worldbank2017,
   author = "World Bank",
   title = "A Step Ahead: Competition Policy for Shared Prosperity and Inclusive Growth",
   year = "2017",
   pages = 245,
   url = "https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/content/publication/978-1-4648-0945-3",
   doi = "https://doi.org/https://doi.org/10.1596/978-1-4648-0945-3" 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Quick question: my reference does not show up, in that case should I add the all the path before .bib file here like: `- \addbibresource{/Users/references02.bib}`?

Comment: @joe Yes, this looks correct (don't forget to clean up your bib file to remove illegal characters like `â`)

Comment: Sure it looks like still reference does not show up. Let me configure my TexShop and try again. thanks.

Comment: Can you try with the exact same example and bib file from my post? This way you should see if the configuration is correct or not.

Comment: Sure let me do so, and as you point out, there are so many characters like drÃ©s RodrÃ­guez-C in my bib file, I will let you know if I still get an issue. thanks

Comment: After spending quite a time, I just post this problem. Could you take a look at here if you have any chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70490503/references-are-missing-in-after-i-run-biblatex