# References do not show up after I run Biblatex in rmarkdown latex

Tags: latex, r-markdown, biblatex

My `biblatex` does not generate **references** section with the following error:
I have a difficulty finding the source of problem.
I am using `TexShop` and already refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations, but it is still not working. I am not sure if it is configuration problem in TexShop or coding issue somewhere else.

```
Warning message:
Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
ick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} into 
your preamble.
 on input line 125.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'ennis2019' on page 1 undefined on input line 129.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'worldbank2017' on page 1 undefined on input line 129.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 131.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                table.markup
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

```
---
title: "Paper"   
thanks: 
author: |
  | \normalfont Joe
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: true
    fig_height: 4.5
    fig_width: 8
toc: false
in_header: preamble.tex
keep_tex: yes
fontsize: 11pt
linestretch: 1.3
subparagraph: true
number_sections: true
geometry: margin=1in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{amsthm}
- \numberwithin{equation}{section}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{geometry}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \usepackage{verbatim}
- \usepackage{chronosys}
- \usepackage{stackengine}
- \usepackage{booktabs, colortbl, xcolor}
- \usepackage[english]{babel}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
- \usepackage[font=small]{caption}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage{tabularx}
- \usepackage{pgfplots}
- \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
- \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
- \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
- \usepackage{filecontents}
- \newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
- \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
- \newtheorem{algorithem}{Algorithm}
- \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
- \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
- \usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
- \newenvironment{rcases}
  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}
- \renewcommand{\refname}{References}
- \UseRawInputEncoding
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \hypersetup{
     colorlinks=true,
     linkcolor=black,
     filecolor=blue,
     citecolor = blue,      
     urlcolor=blue,
     }
- \usepackage{subcaption}
- \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{flafter}
- \floatstyle{plaintop}
- \restylefloat{table}
- \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
- \setlength{\parskip}{0em}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage[style=english]{csquotes} 
- \usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}
- \creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{(\textcolor{red}{#1})}#3}
- \creflabelformat{figure}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \creflabelformat{table}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \creflabelformat{section}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \usepackage{dcolumn}
- \usepackage{rotating}
- \usepackage{siunitx}
- \usepackage[natbib, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
- \addbibresource{Users/references022.bib}
---


blah blah  \cite{ennis2019} \cite{worldbank2017}

\printbibliography
```

```
@article{ennis2019,
    author = {Ennis, Sean F and Gonzaga, Pedro and Pike, Chris},
    title = "{Inequality: A hidden cost of market power}",
    journal = {Oxford Review of Economic Policy},
    volume = {35},
    number = {3},
    pages = {518-549},
    year = {2019},
    month = {07},
    issn = {0266-903X},
    doi = {10.1093/oxrep/grz017},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1093/oxrep/grz017},
    eprint = {https://academic.oup.com/oxrep/article-pdf/35/3/518/28929084/grz017.pdf},
}

@book{worldbank2017,
   author = "World Bank",
   title = "A Step Ahead: Competition Policy for Shared Prosperity and Inclusive Growth",
   year = "2017",
   pages = 245,
   url = "https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/content/publication/978-1-4648-0945-3",
   doi = "https://doi.org/https://doi.org/10.1596/978-1-4648-0945-3" 
}
```

My output is:

[image]

Comment: What output do you get if you run `biber your_filename_without_extension`?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, sorry could you give me a bit more details on your question? Honestly I don't understand the part: run biber your_filename_without_extension. I attached my output above anyhow. thanks again.

Comment: I'm not familiar with texshop, so no idea if there is a build in way to do that. But if you have a terminal/command line and go to the folder of your .rmd and .tex file and run `biber filename` (without the extension .tex) [if there is not yet a .tex file, compile the .rmd file first, the `keep_tex: true` line in your header should make sure that an .tex file is created]

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, sure thank. may I ask what kind of editor are you using? I just want to replace mine by your editor if necessary.

Comment: For .rmd files I use RStudio and for normal .tex files TeXstudio

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, Strangely, when I run biber filename, I got the error: cannot find control file `filename.bcf` although I compiled already .rmd and got .tex file in my folder.

Comment: Urrg, looks like something fishy is going on. Does it work if you run `latexmk name_of_tex_file_without_ending`?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I guess so. When I run, I got `! I can't find file name_of_tex_file_without_ending.`

Comment: Can you try with a filename that does not has periods in it?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, do you mean .rmd file ?

Comment: I mean the .tex file. And then try again `latexmk newfilename`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I think I am totally lost somewhere. I first changed .rmd file name as `table_markup.Rmd` and run it, generating `table_markup.tex` then I tried `latexmk newfilename` in terminal, and this is what I got. 
------------
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 March 2019, version: 4.63b.
Latexmk: Disallowing switch of output file as incompatible
    with file requests. Latexmk: Could not find file 'newfilename'.
-- Use the -f option to force complete processing.

Comment: replace "newfilename" with the new file name you choose. That was just a placeholder

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, thanks so much. finally works!! (want to cry) many thanks again!!

Comment: You're welcome! And sorry for the confusion with the placeholder name.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, so do you suggest that I should change all .rmd and .tex file names without period for example, `table.makrup.tex` to `table_markup.tex`?

Comment: I would use CamelCase, e.g. `TableMarkup.tex`. In some older versions special characters like `_` or spaces can cause problems. With CamelCase you are on the safe side.